# How can we refilter datatable by only specifying custom filter name in webix?

Tags: datatable, webix

I have used `dtable.filterByAll();` but it refilters datatable by all the specified filters but I need to refilter datatable by only one specific filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use the combination of [getFilter()](https://docs.webix.com/api__ui.datatable_getfilter.html) and [filter()](https://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.datatable_filter.html) methods, though it can depend on the case specifics.